# Resolving symbols differently in different dynamically loaded objects

Tags: linux, ld, dynamic-linking, dynamic-loading, symbol-table

After reading [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666248/elf-dynamic-loader-symbol-lookup-ordering) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658809/dynamic-loading-and-weak-symbol-resolution), I'm looking for some more detail about how to control symbol resolution order.

In my problem, I have main executable `exec`. `exec` dynamically links to `a.so` and `c.so`. `a.so` dynamically links to `b.so`. `b.so` calls function `foo`, which is normally provided by `c.so` but in this case is also provided by `exec`. `b.so` only works with `c.so`'s implementation of `foo`.

A diagram of the situation:

```
exec      (foo caller and provider)
   | \
a.so  |
   |  |
b.so  |   (foo caller)
   | /
c.so      (foo provider)
```

I can only control the compilation/source of `a.so`, and I link `a.so` to `exec` with `LD_PRELOAD`.

I'd like calls to `foo` in `exec` to resolve to `exec`'s implementation, and calls in `b.so` to resolve to `c.so`'s implementation. Is this type of thing with different symbol lookups in different objects possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to tweak symbol resolution at per-library level so there is not easy way to achieve this.

<s>If `foo` is actually implemented in main executable (not just [copy-relocated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26863009/whats-the-purpose-of-copy-relocation) to it) there's nothing you can do because symbols from main executables get the highest priority during resolution (unless you are ok with ultimately hacky runtime-patching of GOT which you aren't).</s>

But if

- `foo` is implemented in c.so
- and you are desperate enough

you could do the following:

- get return address inside interceptor in a.so (use `__builtin_return_address`)
- match it against boundaries of b.so (can be obtained from `/proc/self/maps`)
- depending on result, either do special processing (if caller is in b.so) or forward call to `RTLD_NEXT`

This of course has obvious limitations e.g. won't work if b.so calls function from yet another d.so which then calls `foo` but it may be enough in many cases. And yes, I've seen this approach deployed in practice.

Comment: How could I do this with ``dlsym``? I see how ``a.so`` can get reference to ``c.so``'s ``foo`` with ``dlsym``, but is there a way to use ``dlsym`` to make ``b.so`` use it?

Comment: Sorry, misread the question. I've updated the answer, hopefully it's more helpful now.

Comment: thanks for the edit! However, all dependencies only go downwards in the diagram (``a.so`` only calls into ``b.so``), which means the ``__builtin_return_address`` trick won't work. Also, it is actually separate implementations of ``foo`` in ``exec`` and ``c.so``. Are there any resources on GOT hacking (which isn't a road I want to go down but is something I'd like to learn about)?

Comment: "Are there any resources on GOT hacking" - [this one](http://vxheaven.org/lib/vrn00.html#c6) seems to be the most complete. Some parts will be irrelevant to you but parsing ELF and patching GOT seem to be quite generic.

Comment: BTW is `LD_PRELOAD` of a.so critical in your case (e.g. you use it to interpose some symbols in application)? If not, you could instead `dlopen` it with `RTLD_DEEPBIND` from `LD_PRELOAD`-ed intermediate a_forwarder.so. Deep binding will force b.so to prefer symbols from a.so.

Comment: I do have some symbols I want to interpose. Does ``dlopen`` not interpose symbols? From reading about ``RTLD_DEEPBIND``, it sounds like a solution to my problem.

Comment: "Does dlopen not interpose symbols" - no, `dlopen` appends library to the end of search list so it won't interpose symbols provided by libraries that were loaded at program startup. "From reading about RTLD_DEEPBIND, it sounds like a solution to my problem" - unfortunately there's no equivalent of `RTLD_DEEPBIND` for `LD_PRELOAD`-ed libraries.

Comment: Thanks. I think I still have a possible fix by ``LD_PRELOAD``ing ``a_forwarder.so`` which defines the few symbols I want to interpose and then forwards calls to ``dlopen``'d ``a.so``.

Comment: Yes, sounds doable.

Comment: Note that it's possible to auto-generate forwarding for all interesting functions. I once did it in a rather cynical way [here](https://github.com/yugr/sigcheck/blob/master/src/interceptors.c) (the cynical part being not using `dlsym`) but "proper" approach is straightforward as well.